# unable to delet image uploaded on s3 bucket uploaded on previous day

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mern

I want to save my product images in the amazon s3 bucket.. and there is an option to delete the image from the bucket.. but when I try to delete the image uploaded yesterday , the image link is deleted from the database but the image still exists in the s3 bucket...

When I try to delete a photo uploaded on the same day, it succeeds.

```
const uploadToS3 = async (fileKey, fileData, contentType) => {
    const s3 = new aws.S3({
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
      region: region,
    });
  
    const params = {
      Bucket: "thenaturebeautyflower",
      Key: fileKey,
      Body: fileData,
      ContentType: contentType,
    };
  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = s3.upload(params);
      
      upload.on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
        console.log(`Uploaded ${progress.loaded} out of ${progress.total} bytes`);
      });
  
      upload.send((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Upload failed:", err.message);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Upload succeeded:", data.Location);
          resolve(data.Location);
        }
      });
    });
  };
  `
```

```
const deleteProduct = async (productId) => {
    try {
      // Fetch the product details before deleting
      const productToDelete = products.find(
        (product) => product._id === productId
      );

      // Implement the actual deleteProduct functionality
      await fetch(`${host}/api/product/${productId}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),

        },
      });

      // After successful deletion, delete the files from S3
      const s3FileKeys = [productToDelete.picture, productToDelete.pdfFile];
      await deleteFilesFromS3(s3FileKeys);

      // Fetch the updated product list
      await fetchProduct();

      console.log("Product deleted successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error deleting product:", error);
    }
  };

  // Add this function to your ProductState.js
  const deleteFilesFromS3 = async (fileKeys) => {
    // Creating an S3 client with AWS credentials
    const s3 = new aws.S3({
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
      region: region,
    });

    // Specify the common prefix to be removed
    const prefixToRemove =
      "https://thenaturebeautyflower.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/";

    // Iterate through fileKeys and delete each file from S3
    for (const fileKey of fileKeys) {
      // Remove the specified prefix from the file key
      const keyWithoutPrefix = fileKey.replace(prefixToRemove, "");

      // Determine the appropriate prefix based on the file type
      const fileTypePrefix = fileKey.includes("images/") ? "images/" : "pdf/";

      // Add the fileTypePrefix to the filename
      const fileName = `${fileTypePrefix}${keyWithoutPrefix.split("/").pop()}`;

      // Specify the parameters for deleting an object from S3
      const params = {
        Bucket: "thenaturebeautyflower",
        Key: keyWithoutPrefix,
        // VersionId: "null",
      };

      console.log(fileName);

      try {
        // Attempt to delete the object from S3
        await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
        console.log(`File deleted successfully: ${fileKey}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error deleting file from S3: ${fileKey}`, error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: What's the error response from `s3.deleteObject`?

Comment: I'm assuming that you've verified that `s3.deleteObject(...)` is actually being called. Log the keys being deleted to ensure they are what you think they are.

Comment: What, exactly is `keyWithoutPrefix` in this context?  Does it include presigned key information?

Comment: When deleting the object, you need to **provide the full Key**, which makes up the entire filename of the object. Your code is not supplying the full key (including Prefix).

Comment: if there is any error in file path then why the images uploaded on the same day is deleted ...

Comment: my console message is file deleted successfully...File deleted successfully: https://thenaturebeautyflower.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/pool/images/26-01-2024-1706281252067-1-AQUASOURCE.jpg

Comment: If you try to delete an S3 object that doesn't exist, it will report success. It will not fail. You are almost certainly trying to delete the wrong keys which will report success but not actually delete anything. As previously suggested, log and double check the keys that you are deleting. Add them to your post.

Comment: i have already explained if there is any error in key then why the image uploaded on the same day is successfully deleted and i have manually check that its remove from bucket..but when i try to delte image uploaded on previous day .message in console successfully but image is still present in bucet...if any error in key then why the image uploaded on the same day successfully remove from bucket??